# Why doesn't substituting very large $n$ into $(1+1/n)^n$ give values approaching Euler's number $e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, eulers-number-e

I would like to ask what is the Euler's number $e$? I don't understand it.

What I Know:

- $e$ is $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ as $n$ reaches infinity
- $e$ is $2.718281828\ldots$

Question:

> If I input $n = 1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000$, I get $2.718523496\ldots$, which is higher than $2.718281828\ldots$.
>
> If I go on and input $n = 1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000$, I get $3.035035207\ldots$ which is way higher than $2.718281828\ldots$.

I think I missed something or I made a mistake.

> Did I misunderstand the formula? Is the formula and the $2.718281828$ above only an approximation?

I would really appreciate any explanation, clarification, and corrections. :)

Thank you so much for you time!

Comment: I don't know what device you are using, but typically with those kind of exponents and the $1/n$ term approaching ridiculously close to zero, "errors" in the computational method creeps in. That is why technology can never replace actual calculus (or math for that matter)

Comment: Seems like your calculator cannot handle those large numbers. The value of $(1+\frac1n)^n$ increases as $n$ increases, so any number you put in for $n$ should yield something less than $e$.

Comment: Try [this calculator](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html).

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) for details on cancellation problems

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives 2.718281828457686094446059194614153729894722002633161162106...

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone, for your speedy answers and great explanations! I apologize, I only used the desmos scientific calculator. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an error analysis. If
$$a_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$
then
$$\ln a_n=n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}-\cdots\right)=1-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{3n^2}-\cdots.$$
For large $n$, $\ln a_n$ is very close to
$$1-\frac1{2n}$$
and so $a_n$ is close to
$$e\exp(-1/(2n))=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{8n^2}-\cdots\right).$$
Actually the $1/(8n^2)$ term here is spurious as I neglected the $1/(3n^2)$ term
in the expansion of $\ln a_n$. But a crude estimate of $a_n$ is that
$$a_n\approx e-\frac{e}{2n}.$$
The error is slightly worse than $1/n$.

Taking $n=10^{12}$ say, you get about $11$ to $12$ correct decimal places.
The error you get with the calculator is no doubt due to its lack of
precision of its representation of floating point numbers. Probably
[underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math in a computer is not the same as real math computation.  Back when we used $32$ bit floats, which only gave $23$ bits of mantissa, about $7.2$ decimal digits, it was a problem everybody worried about and large sections of numerical analysis courses concentrated on avoiding the problems of numerical precision.  Now that floats are $64$ bits with $53$ bits of mantissa the problem has been greatly reduced, but it still can have a problem.  When you raise to a very small power you can think about $(1+\frac 1n)^n=e^{(\log(1+\frac 1n)n)}$ and expand $\log(1+\frac 1n)$ in a Taylor series.